# comparing list of dict and list and get corresponding value's key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists, `lst` and `my_dict`. `lst` is storing IDs and `lst_of_dict` is a dictionaries with keys and values of ID.

Here I want to extract keys from `lst_of_dict` and add them into a new list if the corresponding values are matched with the ID of `lst`.

Here is the examples:

```
lst = [1, 2, 5]
my_dict = {'44': 2, '801': 1, '7': 5}
```

given these lists, I want to create a new list like below:

```
new_lst = [801, 44, 7]
```

How do you accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

[EDIT]
I'm really sorry but type of `lst_of_dict` is a `dict`, I was wrong.

Comment: Invert the dict with `invert = { v:int(k) for k,v in lst_of_dict.items() }`.  Now you can look up the items directly.

Comment: `lst_of_dict` is not dict. how can `.items()` work?

Comment: @TimRoberts, ```lst_of_dict``` is a list of dictionary, not a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the list of dictionaries and use `index` to replace the values in a copy of the original list (or just the original list if you don't want to preserve it)

```
lst = [1, 2, 5]
my_dict = {'44': 2, '801': 1, '7': 5}

new_lst = lst[:]
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    new_lst[new_lst.index(v)] = int(k)

print(new_lst) # [801, 44, 7]
```

Edit:

If there might be a mismatch between the values in the list and the dictionary you can initialize the new list with `None`s and filter them afterwards

```
new_lst = [None] * len(lst)
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if v in lst:
        new_lst[lst.index(v)] = int(k)

new_lst = list(filter(lambda x: x, new_lst))
```

Comment: your solution doesn't pass my test yet. can you post full code, i'm afradi i output the wrong variable.

Comment: @LeiYang well the OP changed the question.

Comment: but what if the dict **miss** some keys from lst? the OP says **if** the corresponding...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can do it:

```
lst = [1, 2, 5]
lst_of_dict = [
{'44': 2},
{'801': 1},
{'7': 5}
]
invert = {i:int(k)for v in lst_of_dict for k,i in v.items()}
print([invert.get(x) for x in invert])

#== Output [44, 801, 7]
```

Comment: The OP want specific order `[801, 44, 7]`